# --How to make this React/Redux code DRY

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have repetitive code that I do not know how to make DRY ( Don't Repeat Yourself ).

Here are two components "talking" via `dispatch()` and React's auto re-render.

`this.map` is repeated twice.

This module will dispatch actions on a click.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
class Icon extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.map = {
      paper: 'bg_paper.jpg',
      light_wood: 'bg_wood.jpg',
      graph: 'bg_graph.jpg'
    };
  }

  flip () {
    this.props.dispatch({type: 'updateIcon', bg_key: $A.nextKey(this.map, this.props.state.bg_key)});
  }

  render () {
    const style = {
      // ... snip
    }

    return (
      <img id = 'bar_icon' onClick={this.flip.bind(this)} style={style} src='_images/sv_favicon.svg'/>
    )

  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    state: state.Icon
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Icon);
```

while this component will auto re-render.  It all works fine.  I just want to make it DRY.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

// ... snip

class FrameBody extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.map = {
      paper: 'bg_paper.jpg',
      light_wood: 'bg_wood.jpg',
      graph: 'bg_graph.jpg'
    };
  }

  render () {

    const style = {
      backgroundImage: 'url(' + '_images/' + this.map[this.props.state.bg_key] + ')'
    };

    return (

      <div id='contents' style={style}>
      </div>

    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    state: state.Icon
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(FrameBody);
```

What can I do so that there are not two instances of this.map?

Comment: This kind of question might be a good candidate for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the logic of this.map out to a class function.

```
getBackgroundImageKey = () => {
  const backgroundMap = {
    paper: 'bg_paper.jpg',
    light_wood: 'bg_wood.jpg',
    graph: 'bg_graph.jpg'
  }
  return backgroundMap[this.props.bg_key]
}
```

Take a step further and add another function to return the URL and add string interpolation.

```
getBackgroundImageURL(){
  const backgroundMap = {
    paper: 'bg_paper.jpg',
    light_wood: 'bg_wood.jpg',
    graph: 'bg_graph.jpg'
  }
  return `url(_images/${backgroundMap[this.props.bg_key]})`;
}
```

Which will let you define the style like this

```
const backgroundImage = this.getBackgroundImageURL()
const style = { backgroundImage };
```

Comment: But the question was how do I make my code DRY.  I would still need the function in both components.

Comment: DRY doesn't mean a function can only be called once, especially in different contexts. It does mean, however, that you don't redefine the same data in several places, and stateless's answer achieves that.

Answer (score 0):

Well since you're already using Redux and dispatching an action to flip, why don't you move that logic there?

Keep the current image in the store so you can get it in `connect`, make your flip action creator a thunk that holds that "map" and decides what's the next image.

Instead of DRYness, your code lacks separation of concerns. The switch/Icon UI component would be much more reusable and terse if it only called a prop whenever the user clicks "flips". Connect this `onFlip` to the action creator I mentioned and you have the logic in one place, and the UI to interact in another.